# Tracing the source of DNS failure

Tags: domain-name-system

Googlebot is failing to index my domain for DNS reasons, so I looked up my site on a DNS site, and I got this:

> Lookup failed after 2 name servers timed out or responded
>   non-authoritatively
>
> MXTB-PWS3v2 7488ms   0  d.ns.at  81.91.161.98  NON-AUTH  171 ms 
>   Received 2 Referrals , rcode=NO_ERROR
>   NS    dns1.50webs.com,NS  dns2.50webs.com,
>
> 1  dns1.50webs.com  162.210.101.84  NON-AUTH  171 ms  Timeout after
>   3 sec, rcode=NO_ERROR
>
> 1  dns2.50webs.com  162.210.101.95  NON-AUTH  171 ms  Timeout after
>   3 sec, rcode=NO_ERROR

is that a sign of a problem on the hosting end? on the DNS end at my domain registrar, Dynadot? on the DNS end at NIC.AT? on the DNS end at 50webs?

## Edit: more information

The domain is weisbl.at.

The output I gave before is from mxtoolbox.com/DNSLookup.aspx.

I'll post more info when I get a chance later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We start by checking your whois record to see who your authoritative nameservers are set to:

```
$ whois weisbl.at
....
nserver:        dns1.50webs.com
nserver:        dns2.50webs.com
```

Those being the authoritative nameservers for your domain, each of them should be providing the world with answers with respect to your domain.

However, they do not...

```
$ host -t soa weisbl.at dns1.50webs.com
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

$ host -t soa weisbl.at dns2.50webs.com
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I was able to ping these machines, so I suspect they are simply dropping the queries. This suggests that these servers haven't been set up correctly to serve your domain. This makes your next step to contact them and find out why.

Comment: (It's working now, just checked: http://ip.seveas.net/dnsgraph/png/weisbl.at/?skip_.=on&show_A=Show)